# Can Python Timer be canceled by checking if it exists?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I want to check if the timer exists and simply stop it by running the following code a second time, but instead it waits for the timer to stop 
and runs again.

```
import time
import threading


def run():
    print("foobar")

t = threading.Timer(3, run)

def stop_t():
    time.sleep(1)
    t.cancel()
    print("canceled")


if t.is_alive():
    t.cancel()
else:
    t.start()
```

Comment: I can't exactly understand your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: By exists you mean started right? because `is_alive()` tells you if the timer has started,

Comment: yes, point to start timer< and then code was run second-time check Timer, if its in wait stage stop it

Comment: I tried to explain the problem to you and tell you how to fix it in an answer, please tell me if that is not fixing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you run this code again, you will redefine the t variable to a new timer that has not started yet, you can try something like this:

```
import time
import threading


def run():
    print("foobar")

def toggle_timer(t):
    if t.is_alive():
        print('timer is alive, killing it')
        t.cancel()
    else:
        t.start()
        print('timer is dead, starting it')

t = threading.Timer(3, run)
toggle_timer(t)
toggle_timer(t)
```

Output:

> timer is dead, starting it
>
> timer is alive, killing it

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is works ones while code was executing, I need to run this code twice with start timer and stop it, but (?) it wait for a callback from Timer< and  not started again ether

Comment: For example, if start stop_t func, with delay less than Timer, its works ok and cancel it just right, the problem is if I try to execute code while Timer is active its wait for timer event and start it again.